# Create master view from array of tables passed as input to stored procedure Snowflake

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a master view combining all the tables passed as input to Snowflake Stored procedure. Please help on how the code can be framed for this.

create or replace procedure TEST_PROC("SRC_DB" VARCHAR(30),
"SRC_SCHEMA" VARCHAR(30), "TGT_DB" VARCHAR(30), "TGT_SCHEMA"
VARCHAR(30))

```
  RETURNS varchar

  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT

  EXECUTE AS OWNER

as

$$
var result = '';

var tab = 'TABLE1,TABLE2'
var get_tables = `
with cte as(select value from table(SPLIT_TO_TABLE 
(('${tab}'),','))
) select value from cte;`
var tables_name_master=snowflake.execute ({sqlText: get_tables});
var lcols_agg = '';

while(tables_name_master.next()){
var table_value = tables_name_master.getColumnValue(1); 

var column_list = `
WITH cte2 as (select COLUMN_NAME , listagg(TABLE_NAME, ', ') 
within group (order by COLUMN_NAME)  A
    from  ${SRC_DB}.information_schema.COLUMNS 
    where TABLE_SCHEMA= '${SRC_SCHEMA}' and TABLE_NAME in (select 
value from table(SPLIT_TO_TABLE (('${tab}'),',')))
 group by COLUMN_NAME order by COLUMN_NAME
),

 cte3 as (select 'x' x, COLUMN_NAME,iff(contains(A,'${table_value}'),COLUMN_NAME,CONCAT('NULL AS \"',COLUMN_NAME,'\"')) valuess from cte2 order by COLUMN_NAME
    )select listagg(valuess,',') final FROM cte3 GROUP BY x
    `;

var rs = snowflake.execute({ sqlText: column_list });
while(rs.next()){
lcols_agg += "SELECT " + rs.getColumnValue(1) + " FROM "+ SRC_DB+"."+SRC_SCHEMA+"."+tables_name_master.getColumnValue(1) + "\n" +"UNION " +"\n"
}
      }
var count1 = 0 ;
count1 = lcols_agg.length
result =   lcols_agg.substring(0,(count1-7)); 

const create_union_view = `
        create or replace view abcd AS ${result}
;`
var view_create = snowflake.execute({ sqlText: create_union_view });
view_create.next()
return result

$$
;

call  SP_TEST('ABC','DEF','PQR','STU');

THis generates my final view statement as 
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ABCD AS 
COL1,COL2,COL3
UNION
NULL AS "COL2",NULL AS "COL3",COL1

Now due to mismatch of order od columns in union the view is throwing error while we do select * from abcd, any way we can have the columns of both tables in same order or any other work around?
```

Comment: Please explain with more detail what you have and the desired end result

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by master view?

Comment: I have updated it,@FelipeHoffa @eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ORDER BY the function listagg after the cte3 expression:

instead of

```
select listagg(valuess,',') final FROM cte3 GROUP BY x
```

change it to:

```
select listagg(valuess,',') within group (order by valuess) final FROM cte3 GROUP BY x
```

See if that helps to resolve the order issue.

Comment: this solves the issues, thanks for the insight much helpful!